# How can I permanently grant permission for navigator.clipboard in a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, permissions

I'm trying to use `navigator.clipboard.readText()` in a tab opened by my Google Chrome extension. When I do, the below permission alert appears on every page load, even though I have granted the permission already:

[image]

This is the relevant code:

```
<button onclick="getClipboardContents()">Add</button>

<script>
  async function getClipboardContents() {
    try {
      const text = await navigator.clipboard.readText();
      console.log('Pasted content: ', text);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Failed to read clipboard contents: ', err);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Is there a way to stop this message from appearing every time?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a working example.

Comment: Why is this tagged google-chrome-extension? Because for a page in an extension, the answer may be different. But there isn't any indication in the question that this is the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't specify how you are opening the page. The permission dialog indicates that you are accessing it via a `file://` URL. Tabs, opened by an extension should have a `chrome-extension://` URL and the permission dialog should show the name of your extension :

[image]

You need to add the `clipboardRead` permission to your `manifest.json` and open the tab with `chrome.tabs.create()` and `chrome.runtime.getURL()`. When done in this manner, the permission dialog should only appear on the first page load and not every time.

Here is a minimal reproducible example :

### manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Clipboard Test",
  "version": "0.1",
  "permissions": [
    "clipboardRead"
  ],
  "action": {},
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

### background.js

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(currentTab => {
  chrome.tabs.create({
    'url': chrome.runtime.getURL("test.html")
  });
});
```

### test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title> Clipboard Test </title>
<button id="test"> TEST </button>
<script src="clip.js"></script>
```

### clip.js

```
const button = document.querySelector('button#test');

async function paste() {
  let text = await navigator.clipboard.readText();
  alert(text);
}

button.addEventListener('click', paste);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simply impossible. Google Chrome displays such an alert so that the user can either grant clipboard privileges or deny the privileges.